# No internet connection when getting out of hibernation

Tags: 13.10, internet, suspend, hibernate

Lately when I'm returning to Ubuntu 13.10 from hibernation I get no internet connection.

The networking is off and I can't get it to turn on unless I suspend the computer and then resume usage.

Any idea on what that could be and how I could fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that hibernation performs a software lock on your network interfaces, making them unavailable. Resuming after suspension may reverse this lock.

Go into hibernation, and once you're back with no connections available, type :

```
rfkill unblock all
```

This should remove any lock applied on your interfaces. If you want to be more specific (not unlock `all` interfaces), use :

```
rfkill list
```

You'll get numbers associated to your interfaces, which you can use in the `unblock` command afterwards, instead of `all`.

Edit : maybe have a look here ?
http://oleeekchoff.blogspot.ie/2012/05/restart-modulesservices-after.html

Comment: Cool. Will check.
I will have to repeat the "rfkill unblock all" command each time though, wouldn't I? It won't be a permanent solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that getting out of hibernation triggers an event somewhere, to which you could associate this command. I don't really know that subject, maybe you'll find something here : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnderstandingSuspend